# Javascript loop displaying x2 of what i added

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have been working on a website which displays images to download it worked pretty good but I wanted to make a script of putting tag so when people use search bar to find images it would be easier for them.

I found a script from internet and tried to put it on my website and it actually works but the problem is that it displays x2 of what I added

```js
var crosshairs = [{
    "file": "1.png",
    "tags": "yellow, simple, edgy"
  },
  {
    "file": "2.png",
    "tags": "blue, grey, round"
  },
  {
    "file": "3.png",
    "tags": "small, black, yellow"
  },
  {
    "file": "4.png",
    "tags": "blue, big"
  },
  {
    "file": "5.png",
    "tags": "blue, small"
  },
  {
    "file": "6.png",
    "tags": "black, red, small"
  },
  {
    "file": "7.png",
    "tags": "red, black, big, round"
  },
  {
    "file": "8.png",
    "tags": "blue, red, white, round"
  },
  {
    "file": "9.png",
    "tags": "black, purple, small"
  },
  {
    "file": "10.png",
    "tags": "blue, purple, small"
  },
]

$.each(crosshairs, function(index, crosshair) {
  $('.content').append('<a href="content/' + crosshair.file + '" class="crs" download="siteM16.png" data-tags="' + crosshair.tags + '"><img src="content/' + crosshair.file + '"/></a>');
});

$("input").keyup(function() {
  $(".content a").show();
  search = $("input").val().split(" ");

  $(".content a").each(function() {
    tags = $(this).data("tags");
    element = $(this);

    $.each(search, function(index, value) {
      if (!tags.includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
        element.hide();
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: I created you a snippet to make a [mcve]

Comment: If you have more than one thing with class="content" you will get an image per container. Please update the snippet with your actual HTML

Comment: it doesnt fix anything sir, i just copied and pasted ur code into my but it doesnt work. one thing i noticed i just copied ur 10 var but when i search it displays all files

Comment: do you want me to put my .html?

Comment: I cannot look over your shoulder . I did not changer your code other than cut the data to 10. Please edit your post and paste the html you use instead of what I guessed

Comment: added html code

Comment: Your content already has images in it before you append !

Comment: Iam really shit at it, can you help me fix the script ? iam still learning...

Comment: nvm fixed it thanks for the help really appreciate it!

Comment: Feel free to delete the question since it is not solving any issue for people who come later

Answer (score 0):

You are adding crosshair.file twice in your 2nd line. Try only adding once.

Also, your title says JavaScript and then your question says Java scripting (should be one word or else people may think you are referring to JAVA) and your code looks like jQuery??

Comment: What is adding what twice? can you paste the line you mean?

Comment: Isn't one `crosshair.file` for `<img>` and the other for `<a>`?